# adding and removing shapes continuously in a loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to write a program that displays 10 randomly colored and randomly located boxes, but according to the assignment, "Only the last 10 random boxes are to be displayed on the screen. That is, when the 11th box is drawn, remove the 1st box that was drawn. When the 12th box is drawn, remove the 2nd box, and so on".

I'm not sure how to do this, as the farthest I can get is to use a for loop to display 10 random boxes.

This is what I have so far:

```
package acm.graphics;

import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ShootingStar extends GraphicsProgram
{
    public void run()
    {
        final int width = 800;
        final int height = 600;
        final int boxWidth = 50;
        final int maxBoxes = 10;

        this.setSize(width, height);
        Random random = new Random();

        for( int i = 0; i<=maxBoxes ;i++) {

            float r = random.nextFloat();
            float b = random.nextFloat();
            float g = random.nextFloat();
            Color randColor = new Color(r,g,b);

            GRect r1 = new GRect(boxWidth, boxWidth);
            r1.setFilled(true);
            r1.setColor(randColor);

            GPoint x = new GPoint(random.nextInt(width), 
                                random.nextInt(height));

            add(r1, x);

        }

        this.pause(100); 
    }
}
```

please any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: YOu should really mention what is the problem with the current code. What is it missing to achieve what you need?

Comment: currently it only displays the 10 random boxes, but does not continue to add and remove boxes

Comment: Think this out on paper.  What is the pseudo-code needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it would be:

```
public class Test {
private int boxWidth, boxHeight = 50;
private GRect[] rects;
private int first;//keep track of oldest rectangle

public Test()
{
    this.rects = new GRect[10];
    this.first = 0;
}

void drawRects()
{
    //for each rectangle, draw it
}

void addRect()
{
    this.rects[first] = new GRect(boxWidth, boxHeight);
    first++;
    first = first % 10; //keeps it within 0-9 range
}

 }
```

Just call addRect() whenever a new rectangle needs to be added and the new one will replace the oldest one.

Answer (score 0):

You're only iterating ten times, which only makes ten boxes, right? Let's start there. maxBoxes should be larger than 10 (I don't know the specifics of what you're trying to do, so I can't say what maxBoxes should be)

Basically, you want to store the information for these boxes somewhere, and then pull the last ten items out. You could use an array of arrays for this. If you're pushing to then end of the main array, then you just have to pop off the last ten, then draw the boxes.